# My application with ionic/capacitor 4 does not show the splash screen

Tags: android, angular, ionic4, capacitor

It only shows a blank screen, it doesn't even show the screen that capacitor shows by default

this is my capacitor.config.ts

```
  plugins: {
    SplashScreen: {
      launchAutoHide: false,
      androidScaleType: "CENTER_CROP",
      splashFullScreen: true,
      splashImmersive: true,
      androidSplashResourceName: "splash"
    }
  }
```

this is my styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
</style>


<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/splash</item>
</style>
```

Comment: In which android version are you testing?